# How to handle authorship for reports/papers?

Tags: authorship

I am currently reviewing a technical report and have direct access to the source files on Overleaf as well as communication with the author. I made some revisions to the manuscript to ensure it meets high-quality standards, such as adding an introduction, correcting the abstract, rewording sections for clarity, making the language more formal, and correcting formulas. These revisions do not significantly impact the theory but improve the overall presentation.

Since I am not the original author of the report, I wonder how my contributions should be acknowledged. I suggest including me in the acknowledgment section. Does this work qualify me as an author? if not what?

Comment: It's not really clear what your role actually is. What do you mean by "I am currently reviewing a technical report"? Did the author ask you to improve the manuscript or is this your own decision?

Comment: I was asked to review and provide feedback, but I decided to make some additional changes because Overleaf make it easy.

Comment: Is the author aware that you have unilaterally decided to start editing their manuscript? Are you sure that they are okay with it? For example, I imagine I would be pretty pissed off if someone who is not a co-author just decided to start "improving" a manuscript of mine without express permission to do so (above and beyond correcting obvious typos). But of course, it may be that the author of the report has a different attitude and had different expectations in mind when they asked you to review their report.

Comment: Notice the modifications I do are in form of suggestions in the text. The platform has track-changes, so they can accept/discard all my changes and it's fine. They come to me expecting to improve the text and presentation somehow.